# Tikz: Filling Parabola and Rounde Arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, fillbetween

I edited my code to fill the area and plot the round arrow. The arrowhead shows upwards as shown here:

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3751/q4ohidu4_pdf.htm

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{1.0,0.2,0.2}

\begin{figure} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
 %\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (10,10);
 \draw [->, thick] (-3,0) -- (0,0) -- (3,0);
 \node at (3.2,0) {$\vec{k}$};
 \draw [->, thick] (0,0) -- (0,5);
 \node at (0,5.5) {$\varepsilon(\vec{k})$};
 \draw [thick, domain=-2:2] plot (\x, {\x*\x});
 \draw [thick, dashed] (-2,3.0) -- (2,3.0);
 \draw [fill, red] (1,3) circle [radius=0.05];
 \draw [fill, red] (2,4.2) circle [radius=0.05];
 \draw [fill, red] (3,2) circle [radius=0.05]; 
 \draw [thick] (2.5,2) -- (3.5,2);
 \draw [->, thick] (3,1.70) -- (3,2.30);
 \begin{scope}
    \clip [domain=-2:2]plot (\x, {\x*\x});
    \fill [darkgray, opacity=0.4] (-2,0) rectangle (2,3);
 \end{scope}
 \draw[thick,-stealth] plot [smooth,tension=.55] coordinates {(3.0,2.0) (2,4.2) (1.0,3.0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I compiled your code here and I got the right result (arrow pointing downward). I suspect you are running a not-up-to-date version of TikZ, can you check what version are you running?

Comment: Hey, how can I check / update my version of TikZ? I'm using Kile for working and the basic version of TikZ which was automatically installed with Kile.

Comment: @Deuterium42 Could you join the following chat room? It is a bit difficult to go through this inside comments: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17317/discussion-between-dcmst-and-deuterium42

Comment: Hey, I just have 11 reputation and need 20 to use the chat.

Comment: @Deuterium42 now you can :) Thanks to the voters!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (10,10);

 \draw [->, thick] (-3,0) -- (0,0) -- (3,0);
 \node at (3.2,0) {$\vec{k}$};
 \draw [->, thick] (0,0) -- (0,5);
 \node at (0,5.5) {$\varepsilon(\vec{k})$};
 \draw [thick, domain=-2:2] plot (\x, {\x*\x});
 \begin{scope}
    \clip [domain=-2:2]plot (\x, {\x*\x});
    \fill [blue, opacity=0.4] (-2,0) rectangle (2,3);
 \end{scope}
 \draw [thick, dashed] (-2,3.0) -- (2,3.0);
 \draw [fill, red] (1,3) circle [radius=0.05];
 \draw [fill, red] (2,4.2) circle [radius=0.05];
 \draw [fill, red] (3,2) circle [radius=0.05];
 \draw [thick] (2.5,2) -- (3.5,2);
 \draw[thick,-stealth] plot [smooth,tension=.55] coordinates {(3.0,2.0) (2,4.2) (1.0,3.0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

You need to `clip` the parabola for the filling. To connect the points you can use a plot with coordinates. The `tension` option will change the "roundness" of the curve, `.55` is the default value.

[image]

Comment: Hi, tanks for your fast answer. I added your lines and the filling works. But I got a little problem with the arrow. The arrow is smooth now, but the arrow head does not point at the red dot. In my file it points upwards ... any idea why?

Comment: @Deuterium42 If you copy-paste the following line `\draw[thick,-stealth] plot [smooth,tension=.55] coordinates {(3.0,2.0) (2,4.2) (1.0,3.0)};`exactly as it is into your code you got a different result than the one in the picture?

Comment: Yes. I retried (copy + paste) it but still the same problem. Is it possible to upload the picture and show it to you? If yes, how?

Comment: @Deuterium42 you can edit the question and insert a link to some service where you have uploaded the image. I suggest to edit the question, insert the new code (with the modification taken from my answer) in a compilable form and the link to the result you got when compiling.

Answer (score 4):

With `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[
     axis lines=middle,
    axis equal,
    grid=both,
    xlabel=$\vec{k}$,
    ylabel=$ε(\vec{k})$,
    no marks,
    domain=-2:2,
    xmax=4,xmin=-3,ymax=3,ymin=0,samples=100,
    ]
       \addplot[red,thick,name path=a] {(x^2)};
       \addplot[blue,thick,name path=b,dashed] {2} ;
       \addplot[fill=none] fill between[of=a and b,split,
           every segment no 1/.style={fill,orange,opacity=.4},] ;
       \draw [fill, red] (axis cs: 1,3) circle [radius=0.05];
        \draw [fill, red] (axis cs: 2,4.2) circle [radius=0.05];
        \draw [thick] (axis cs: 2.5,2) -- (axis cs: 3.5,2);
        \draw [fill, red] (axis cs: 3,2) circle [radius=0.05];
        \addplot[->,thick,smooth,samples=100] coordinates{
       (3.0,2.0) (2,4.2) (1.0,3.0)};
     \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]